# Short stay visa to Romania

Tags: indian-citizens, romania

I'm an Indian national British Resident. I've planned to go to Romania for vacation with friends.

From what I've seen on their [website](http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2046) I would need a short stay visa.

1. What I understand is I come under the type "C/TU". Is that right?
2. There is no visa processing time given in the website. Does anyone know how long does it take?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's true, you need to have C/TU visa type.

It usually takes from 7 to 15 days to issue a Short stay visa. However, if you are in hurry, you may pay extra fee for an emergency processing (3 days)

Comment: From the website (http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2058) I've been told to submitted my application to the diplomatic missions and consular posts.

I live in London, here are my questions:

1." M.E.I.C. House, 344 Kensington High Street, London W14 8NS" is this the address I should come to submit my application?
2. What are the opening timings?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. You may apply for or collect the Romanian Visa, in person, based on prior appointment, TUESDAY from 14.00 to 15.00 hrs or FRIDAY from 10.00 to 11.00 hrs (excluding public holidays) You may find additional information on Romanian visa and make an appointment at http://evisa.mae.ro/.

Comment: They are not offering emergency processing for C/TU visa type at London office.